# How to find the index of a column looking at the value of another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, lookup

I have two dataframes, df1 and df2.

```
df1 =  "R" : ["0.2","0.4","0.55"]
         "Aa" : ["1","2","3']
         "Ba" : ["5","6","6"]
 
df2 = "Rate" : ["0.2","0.55","0.2"]
       "C"   :["Aa","Aa","Ba"]
```

I want my code to look at values in C and return the df1 Column index that matches the exact Column C value

expected output:

```
C

Aa 1
Aa 1
Ba 2
```

Comment: What you have is not valid Python. Can you please show a [mre]?

Answer (score 2):

Apply mapping between column names and their positions:

```
col_map = dict(zip(df1.columns, range(df1.columns.size)))
c_idx = pd.Series(df2['C'].map(col_map).values, index=df2['C'].values)
print(c_idx)
```

---

```
Aa    1
Aa    1
Ba    2
```

Comment: Your country is at war, thank you for helping people here and having time for us.